# How to set x,y in ggplot aes with one dimension dataframe?

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
df <- data.frame(
    cola = c('1',NA,'c','1','1','e','1',NA,'c','d'),
    colb = c("A",NA,"C","D",'a','b','c','d','c','d'),
    colc = c('a',NA,'c','d','a',NA,'c',NA,'c','d'),stringsAsFactors = TRUE)

bad<-lapply(df, function(x) sum(is.na(x))/nrow(df))
bad<-as.data.frame(bad)
```

I want to make bar plot  to one dimension dataframe `bad`.

X axis should be `cola`,`colb`,`colc`,Y axis should be `0.2`,`0.1`,`0.3`. Then I tried but failed:

```
ggplot(bad,aes(x=colnames(bad), y=bad[1,])) + 
    geom_bar(stat='identity')
```

As to one dimension dataframe,how to set `aes(x=?,y=?)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change the dimension of the dataframe

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(stack(bad), aes(ind, values)) + geom_bar(stat='identity')
```

[image]

Or if you want to go the `tidyverse` way we can use `gather` as well

```
ggplot(tidyr::gather(bad), aes(key, value)) + geom_bar(stat='identity')
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to convert your data frame to long format. You can use reshape2's melt function.

```
dab <- reshape2::melt(bad)

> dab
  variable value
1     cola   0.2
2     colb   0.1
3     colc   0.3

ggplot(dab) + geom_bar(aes(x=variable, y=value, fill=variable), stat='identity')
```